# MFC OnInitialUpdate never gets called

Tags: c++, visual-c++, mfc

I have a CFormView that is dynamically created at runtime. However, something really weird is going on, because OnInitialUpdate never gets called for that view. I set a breakpoint in the function and it never gets hit once, even though I can see the view being displayed onscreen. This is a problem because whenever I try to work with the view's member controls, the program crashes because they aren't initialized. What gives?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**EDIT:** You can just call OnInitialUpdate manually; you don't necessarily need to override it.

I think I might be a victim of [this](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/491750/cview-oninitialupdate-not-being-called-by-the-mfc-framework-at-random-times) bug. My workaround was to override `OnInitialUpdate()` and call it manually, immediately after my view is dynamically created. This only worked if the very first line in the overridden function was a call to the parent `CFormView::OnInitialUpdate()`.

Comment: Out of curiosity, have you tried the other solution to leave out the `WS_VISIBLE` flag?

Comment: See, I never set it. I used the ClassWizard to add the control variables to the view, so all of the `Create` and `ModifyStyle` methods or whatever else you'd need to create the control manually aren't necessary (according to [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4w0b9a5k.aspx) link).

Comment: And in the properties for the control, visible is set to `False`, so MFC shouldn't use the `WS_VISIBLE` (theoretically, anyway).

Answer (score 1):

I'm currently working round this issue by using CFormView::OnActivateView() instead, then testing/setting a member variable flag (m_bInitialised) so that I can ensure the code I wanted in CFormView::OnInitialUpdate() only gets run the first time.

Seems slightly more self-contained than manually calling OnInitialUpdate() from outside, but at best only slightly less icky :-/